# OAuth with a Dockerized Plumber API in Azure

Tags: r, azure, plumber

I have created an API using R's plumber package and then dockerized the API (https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html#docker).  I can hit the API locally.  I then pushed the docker container to Azure registry and made it into a web app.  I can hit that web app as an API and get a value returned.

The next step that I'm uncertain of how to do is to authenticate the user (for me it's users within my organization that want to call my API within their apps).

How can I authenticate a Dockerized Plumber API in Azure?

Comment: Consider something like [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/api-management/)

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks I'll pursue this route